# intended solution for G&P S1.1

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm working on G&P problem sets to prepare for a comp. Today was day 1! All went fairly well, except this problem here:

> Prove that the hyperboloid in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $x^2+y^2-z^2=a$
>   is a manifold for $a>0$. Why isn't it a manifold when $a=0$?

I've already taken the course, so my first instinct was the following:

**Proof:** Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $(x,y,z)\mapsto x^2+y^2-z^2$. If $a>0$, then for each point $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $f(x,y,z)=a$ we have that $x^2+y^2=a+z^2>0$ and thus that one of $x$ or $y$ is non-zero. Hence, for each such point $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$, the linear map $df_{(x,y,z)}:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$, computed directly as $[2x \ \ 2y \ -2z]$, is surjective; wlog, suppose $x\neq 0$ and set $L=\lbrace (t,0,0) :t\in\mathbb{R}\rbrace$. Then $df_{(x,y,z)}(L)=\mathbb{R}$. Since $df_{(x,y,z)}$ is surjective for all such values, $a$ is a regular value and $f^{-1}(a)$ is a 2-dimensional manifold (preimage theorem).$\blacksquare$

However, this problem is in the first section so I imagine they want a more constructive argument. Since showing that $S^1$ is a manifold was done in the section, I think this is what they wanted. But I'm not sure how to do it this way. I thought about projecting in the following way:

$f:X\to Y$ by $(x,y,z)\to (x,0,z)$ for $x>0$

where $Y$ is the portion grey plane that lies inside of the hyperboloid. So $f$ would only project the upper half of the hyperboloid onto this grey portion, but by symmetry this covers $X$. Here's the problem, though. Even though I think this is doable (so far), how do we know that $Y$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer, just a comment on terminology. There's an error in the problem statement -- this surface is a **_hyperboloid_**, not a paraboloid. @TedShifrin has posted a very helpful list of errata [here](https://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/Guillemin_Pollack_errata.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the preimage theorem is great, we can also use local parametrizations in the same way that G&P parametrized $S^1$. We can parametrize $H_a=\lbrace (x,y,z): x^2+y^2-z^2=a\rbrace$ with four maps. Let $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $g(s,t)=a^2-s^2+t^2$. Then the four maps we will use to parametrize are

$\begin{array}{ll}
\phi_1(x,z)=(x,\sqrt{g(x,z)},z)\quad\text{ for $y>0$,} &\phi_2(x,z)=(x,-\sqrt{g(x,z)},z)\quad\text{ for $y<0$,} \\
\phi_3(y,z)=(\sqrt{g(y,z)},y,z)\quad\text{ for $x>0$,} & \phi_4(y,z)=(-\sqrt{g(y,z)},y,z)\quad\text{ for $x<0$,} 
\end{array}$

Then $\phi_1$ is defined on the region $g^{-1}((0,\infty))$ which is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and and hence an 2-dimensional manifold. The inverse function for $\phi_1$ is $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,z)$ and this is clearly smooth. The other functions are symmetric.

Comment: Since the question contains such a nice picture, let me mention that two of the four maps in this answer are the horizontal projections from the vertical gray plane to the two halves of the hyperboloid, and the other two maps are similar but using the $y$-$z$-plane instead of the $x$-$z$-plane.